# Permission denied when trying to scp through code

Tags: node.js, ssh, scp

I have a problem when I try to download a file from a server.

If I use this command through a shell it works, but when I try to run the command from code, I get permission denied.

```
scp user@host:path localpath
password
```

The code I try to run it from(using simple-ssh to nodejs):

```
sshlocal
        .exec('sudo scp user@host:path localpath' , {
            out: function (msg) {
                io.emit('chat message', msg)
            },
            err: function (stderr) {
                console.log(stderr);
            }
        })
        .exec(pass, {
            out: function (msg) {
                io.emit('chat message', msg)
            },
            err: function (stderr) {
                console.log(stderr); // this-does-not-exist: command not found
            }
        })
       .start();
```

Error message:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Answer (score 1):

**Permission denied**: can you success login to your remote server with ssh direct in your terminal. If success, try to run 'sudo scp user@host:path localpath'.

Comment: I can manually login and do the commands with success in a terminal. It's only when I try to run the code that I get an error.
With sudo it gives this error:
    
    Host key verification failed.

Comment: At remote server , ~/.ssh/known_hosts maybe have changed , you can try to delete the item relate to your "host"